# Does the Taylor/Maclaurin series converges to something known if we replace the factorials by integers ? (or completely remove them)

Tags: taylor-expansion, power-series

EDIT :
I am wondering if
$$
S(x) = {\frac {f'(0)}{1}}x+{\frac {f''(0)}{2}}x^{2}+{\frac {f'''(0)}{3}}x^{3}+\cdots
$$
converges to something known.
As mentioned in a comment by Empy2, this question relates to the complete removal of denominators considering
$$
S'(x) = {f'(0)}\,x+{f''(0)}\,x^{2}+{f'''(0)}\,x^{3}+\cdots
$$

It clearly does for some functions, e.g. with $f(x) = \exp(x)$ for which $S(x)=-\ln(1-x)$ and $S'(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

The initial question was with sum
$$
S(x) = f(0)+{\frac {f'(0)}{1}}x+{\frac {f''(0)}{2}}x^{2}+{\frac {f'''(0)}{3}}x^{3}+\cdots
$$
but the first term should be $f(0)/0$, as mentioned in a comment by mr_e_man. The simplification proposed by Empy2 also removes the first term and this change makes things more clear.

Comment: $S^\prime(x)$ is the same series but without the denominators, which is slightly simpler

Comment: The convergence/closed form depends on $f(x)$, so do you want to put $S(x)$ in terms of a taylor series?

Comment: The first term would be $f(0)/0$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I am wondering if there exists a direct relation between $S$ and $f$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call $S'(x)$ is the Borel integral or Borel sum of $f$.
First note the following

$$
\int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t}dt = n!
$$

So formally

\begin{align}
S'(x) & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^n \int_0^\infty t^n e^{-t}dt \\
&= \int_0^\infty  e^{-t} f(tx) dt . 
\end{align}

Usually this trick is used backward, i.e. by adding a factor of $n!$ in the denominator of its Maclaurin series so as to make it convergent. The integral above (when exist) is a way to give a meaning to a diverging series.

You can look up Borel tranform or Borel summation.